# How to markup advertisement?

Tags: html, social-networking, semantic-markup, ads

How to markup advertisement to have it excluded from search?

My specific problem is that I have the below code outside the `main` and `article` elements on my pages. Going from a purely semantic to a real world problem: Sharing a link to my page on Google+, Facebook, and Twitter will use the advertisement image to represent the content.

```
<aside>
  <a href="http://www.example.com/ad" rel="nofollow">
    <img src="/example_com.png" /></a>
</aside>
```

The social networks’ documentation tells me how to specify which image to use. But for much of my content, no image would be the best option. None of them explain how to achieve that.

For Google Custom Searches I could have tweaked my code to `<aside class="nocontent">` to achieve this. But according to Google’s documentation, this does not affect normal web search. Testing shows that none of the social networks respect this either.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm if I understand you right you want to declare the semantic markup of ads non indexable.

Here's the first place I checked-> http://schema.org/WPAdBlock

Answer (score 1):

If the advertisement is not part of your content (instead of, e.g., a blog post about a product), using the [`aside` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-aside-element) would be correct from the HTML perspective:

> The element can be used […] **for advertising** […]

If some third party services simply scrape *any* image if you don’t provide one with semantic annotations (e.g. in RDFa, Microdata or Metatags), I’d say it’s a bad service.

You could try some "hacks" and then check if these services stop using the ad image:

- use an [`iframe` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-iframe-element) for the advertisement (maybe the services don’t check `iframe` content)
- use the [`object` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-object-element) instead of [`img`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element) (maybe the services only look for `img`)
- load the ad via JavaScript (maybe the services don’t run JS)

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I do not want to make my own code less efficient or semantically correct just to please these third-party services.

Comment: @Aeyoun: Yes, me neither. However, using `iframe` (in addition) resp. `object` (instead of `img`) is semantically fine. Should those tricks not work or if you don’t want to do it, well, what else can you do? You’d have to live with these bad third party services, or try to contact them so they might fix it.