# Semantic sectioning and the effects of an aside advertisement’s own headline

Tags: html, search-engine, semantic-markup, ads

Since `aside` is a new section, it is appropriate to give it a headline. Even for advertisement. You frequently see that around the web, they are just styled to be insignificant.

My question is: given the below code, will search engines interpret my document as being all about ads? I fear that this `h1` element may have that unintended side effect. What is The Right Thing To Do™ here?

I know that at least *Bing Webmaster Central* will complain if your document contains more than one `h1`element. (Which is a bug on their end, of course.)

Code:

```
<!-- appears outside main and article elements -->
<aside>
  <h1>Advertisement</h1>
  <a href="http://example.com" rel="nofollow"><img src="exampleAd.png" /></a>
</aside>
```

Styling:

[image: Example presentation of above code]

Related question: [How to markup advertisement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18087497/656132)

Answer (score 1):

> will search engines interpret my document as being all about ads?

Some search engines are certainly smart enough to understand it, other search engines probably not. It depends on the specific search engine and its current interpretation, as it could change daily.

> What is The Right Thing To Do™ here?

This depends on your priorities.

If we understand the HTML specification as agreement between web authors and user-agent programmers (including browsers and services like search engines), the right thing would be to write your markup according to the HTML spec (and related specs like [WCAG](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/) etc.). Search engines should *follow*, and not try to dominate how web authors should markup their documents.

---

An alternative to your markup could be:

```
<aside>
  <small>Advertisement</small>
  <h1>I love freedom</h1> <!-- or something like that -->
  <a href="http://example.com" rel="nofollow"><img src="exampleAd.png" alt="…" /></a>
</aside>
```

Here the heading is not describing the *kind* of content ("It’s some ad!), but the actual content ("It’s about …!"). Using "Advertisement" as heading would be similar to using "Blog post" as heading for a blog post (instead of "Very cute kitten!"). As soon as users skip to and read this content, the [`small` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-small-element) informs that it’s an adverisement.

Of course there can be a good reason to use "Advertisement" instead: it informs users reading the outline that the following content is an ad and not your own content, so e.g. screen reader users could skip that part. With the heading "I love freedom" screen reader users might think that the following content is your own and start reading it, and only then they’d notice that it’s actually an ad. Depends on which side you are, so to say *;-)*.

Comment: Thank you for your refelctions, @unor. Third-party ad delivery services will not provide a relevant headline. So that is out of the question. I also wanted to have the `aside` have an appropriate name in the outline, which is why I landed on “Advertisement”.

Comment: I contacted _Bing Webmaster Central_ yesterday. The response I got this morning was not from a human. Have requested to have it answered by a human. They also sent me an email with a warning about having multiple `h1`s on one of my documents. Seems they really do not like it.

Comment: @Aeyoun: As I tried to explain, I think in many cases the "I love freedom" (or similar) heading would be even more appropriate than "Advertisement" for the outline. However, if you don’t hand-pick the ads this is not possible, of course :/.

Comment: @Aeyoun: If Bing has such a problem with `h1` in sectioning elements, you could use the corresponding heading level (`h2`-`h6`) instead, which is of course still allowed. You might only lose some flexibility (if you often move sectioning elements around).

Comment: *sigh* The frustrating feeling developers get when they’re technically correct but something which isn’t (reality) forces them to write inelegant/inferior code. This will complicate my stylesheets a lot. I’ll give @unor the correct answer check in a few days if no one else pitches in.

Answer (score 1):

I did a little more digging and stumbled upon another example from [the current spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element):

```
<aside class="advertising">
  <h1>Advertising</h1>
  …
</aside>
```

It would seem to be the intent that ads should be marked up like this.